# How do i make an ascending order an array of strings using the a number within the string?

Tags: java, arrays, substring

I have the number for example 593, I need to order these numbers and put them in ascending order. What I want to know is how to put this in ascending order. This is a few lines from the excel that I have to order.NOTE there all 10,000 lines of these.

```
8/26/2012,Kristina,H,Chung,947 Martin Ave.,Muncie,CA,46489,khchung@business.com, $593 
11/16/2012,Paige,H,Chen,15 MainWay Rd.,Dallas,HI,47281,phchen@business.com, $516 
11/10/2012,Sherri,E,Melton,808 Washington Way,Brazil,CA,47880,semelton@business.com, $80 
9/20/2012,Gretchen,I,Hill,56 Washington Dr.,Atlanta,FL,47215,gihill@business.com, $989 
3/11/2012,Karen,U,Puckett,652 Maplewood Ct.,Brazil,FL,46627,kupuckett@business.com, $826 
7/4/2012,Patrick,O,Song,679 MainWay Rd.,Lafayette,GA,47161,posong@business.com, $652
```

after it was sorted it would look like this

11/10/2012,Sherri,E,Melton,808 Washington Way,Brazil,CA,47880,semelton@business.com, $80
11/16/2012,Paige,H,Chen,15 MainWay Rd.,Dallas,HI,47281,phchen@business.com, $516 
8/26/2012,Kristina,H,Chung,947 Martin Ave.,Muncie,CA,46489,khchung@business.com, $593 
7/4/2012,Patrick,O,Song,679 MainWay Rd.,Lafayette,GA,47161,posong@business.com, $652 
3/11/2012,Karen,U,Puckett,652 Maplewood Ct.,Brazil,FL,46627,kupuckett@business.com, $826 
9/20/2012,Gretchen,I,Hill,56 Washington Dr.,Atlanta,FL,47215,gihill@business.com, $989

but I need to know how to code it to do this.

Some line of code:
        String holder2;
        ArrayList persons = new ArrayList<>();

```
    for(int i = 0; i < listOfCustomers.length; i++)
    {
        holder2 = listOfCustomers[i];
        persons.setData(holder2);   
    }


    Collections.sort(persons);

}
```

Comment: does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What is the expected output for the example you provided?

Comment: The bottom part I added is what i should get after it has gone though the code

Comment: Why not just order them in excel?

Comment: because we cant do that for this

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would go about it :

1. Store these lines in a Srting Array or ArrayList
2. For each line, find the Position of $ by String's chatAt() method and extract the number out of the String
3. Store these Strings in a Map, with key designating the Line number, and value as the Number you extracted in #2
4. Sort the map according to values as given [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-sort-a-map-in-java/)
5. Now you have a map that is sorted according to values and the keys represent the sorting order of the lines!

Answer (score 0):

Create an arrayList:

```
ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
```

Create a class Person that have only a simple field (called data in the example). Create a Person object for every line in the file and call setData. Add them to the list. Use Collections.sort() on the ArrayList after all objects have been added. Loop through the ArrayList and call getData on every item in the list.

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person>{

    private String data;

    /**
     * @return the data
     */
    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    /**
     * @param data the data to set
     */
    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person o) {
        if (getValue(this) < getValue(o)) {
            return -1;
        } else if (getValue(this) > getValue(o)) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private int getValue(Person p) {
        String[] elements = p.getData().split(",");
        String value = elements[elements.length - 1].trim();
        if (value.startsWith("$")) {
            value = value.substring(1);
        }
        return Integer.valueOf(value);
    }

}
```

[See code example of this here](http://www.javadb.com/sort-rows-in-file-based-upon-a-value-on-each-row)

Comment: When i do persons.setData() it tells me to add a cast to it which does not work. What do I do to fix this?

Comment: It is on every Person object that you call setData with the string from the row in the file. On the persons list you call persons.add(person) where person is the instance of the Person class.

Comment: How I have it for me is that my lines from the excel file are in an array called listOfCustomers, this array is a String[]. When every I try to put it in to a holder what I call holder2 for example               holder2 = listOfCustomers[x];                                               then i put person.add(holder2);  it tells me that i need to change holder2 to Person. When i change holder2 to person it does not let me have holder2 = listOfCustomers[x];

Comment: Oh ok, but if you assign the value to holder2, then you can create the Person object (Person person = new Person() ) and call person.setData(holder2). Then use persons.add(person);

Comment: You could of course skip the holder2 variable, and just call person.setData(listOfCustomers[x]);

Comment: is p supposed to be person or a different variable. nvm im dumb. Thank you time to see if it working 100%

Comment: My bad, I realized it just after posting so I edited the post right after. It should be person not p.

Comment: Collection.sort(persons) not person :) It is the list of person-objects that should be sorted, not a single person object.

Comment: ok this is what i have i dont know what is wrong with it  String holder2;
  Person person = new Person();
  ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
  
  for(int i = 0; i < listOfCustomers.length; i++)
  {
   holder2 = listOfCustomers[i];
   person.setData(holder2);
   persons.setData(person); 
  }
  
  
  Collections.sort(persons);
  
 } i can put it in the question if u want to see it better

Comment: Almost there, but you need to create one Person object for every time in the loop, so move that row to be the first below the for statement. Also, the persons.setData(person); should be persons.add(person);

Comment: String holder2;
        ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfCustomers.length; i++) {
            Person person = new Person();
            holder2 = listOfCustomers[i];
            person.setData(holder2);
            persons.add(person);
        }

Comment: now i have to deal with the problem that 1000 is set up as "1,000 "

Comment: In the method getValue of the Person class. Before the line that looks like this: return Integer.valueOf(value); , add this line: value = value.replace(",", "");

Comment: because the "1,000 "" is getting turned in to "000 ""

Comment: Ok nevermind sending me the code, I know what the problem is. We are splitting the line using comma, but there appears to be larger values than in the example above that use comma as separator so we can't use that. Change the line String[] elements = p.getData().split(","); to this instead: String[] elements = p.getData().split("$");

Comment: give me a bit i need to fix other things in the program

Comment: The split method does actually take a regular expression, and since the dollar sign is a important part of regular expressions it actually has to be escaped. p.getData().split("\\$");

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] lines; //Assume initialized

for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    String string = lines[i];
    int number = Integer.valueOf(string.substring(string.lastIndexOf('$') + 1));
    lines[i] = (char)number + string;
}

Arrays.sort(lines);

for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    String string = lines[i];
    lines[i] = string.substring(1);
}

for (String s : lines) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

This sorted 10710 lines in 51ms on my PC. However, note that it will only work if $xxx is less that `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.